# Unable to rip DVD using HandBrake or OGMRip

Tags: dvd, handbrake

I just got my kids some new DVDs, but I am trying to rip them and back them up, since I know they are rough with their discs, and I want to have backups in case the discs become scratched.

However, I am unable to get either HandBrake or OGMRip to rip the disc, closing down in error.

I already made a symlinc from /dev/sr0 to /dev/dvd, I also installed regionset in case the region was wrong (it wasn't).

I am stumped. Could someone take a look at the output of HandBrakeCLI and tell me what's wrong?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
HandBrakeCLI -i /dev/sr0 -o Brave.mp4
[16:19:57] hb_init: starting libhb thread
HandBrake 0.9.8 (2012102600) - Linux x86_64 - http://handbrake.fr
2 CPUs detected
Opening /dev/sr0...
[16:19:57] hb_scan: path=/dev/sr0, title_index=1
libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:157: indx_parse(): error opening /dev/sr0/BDMV/index.bdmv
libbluray/bluray.c:1471: nav_get_title_list(/dev/sr0) failed (0x7fd878000900)
[16:19:57] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
[16:19:57] dvd: Region mask 0xf7
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.3
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdnav: DVD Title: BRAVE
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 412E6DD2
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): BRAVE
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/alberto/.dvdnav/BRAVE.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00f60000. Regions: 1 4

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x000001ff
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x000005cf
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x000005ed
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x0000063c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_0.VOB at 0x00309c86
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB at 0x0030a0be
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_1.VOB at 0x0030d482
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_0.VOB at 0x0030fc31
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_1.VOB at 0x0031a1e8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_1.VOB at 0x00325600
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_13_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_16_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_17_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_18_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_19_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_20_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_0.VOB at 0x0038bb9e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_1.VOB at 0x0038bc21
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_0.VOB at 0x003eeea5
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_1.VOB at 0x003eef15
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_23_1.VOB at 0x003eef2e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 23 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
[16:19:57] scan: DVD has 99 title(s)
[16:19:57] scan: scanning title 1
[16:19:57] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
[16:19:57] scan: duration is 00:00:00 (76 ms)
[16:19:57] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7fd87801f730
[16:19:57] scan: vts=1, ttn=1, cells=0->0, blocks=0->15, 16 blocks
[16:19:57] scan: title 1 has 1 chapters
[16:19:57] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->15 (16), 76 ms
[16:19:57] scan: aspect = 0
[16:19:57] scan: decoding previews for title 1
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00f60000. Regions: 1 4
libdvdnav: decoder.c: [WARNING, unknown bits: 1000000000080000]
libdvdnav: decoder.c: [WARNING, unknown bits: 1000000000000000]
[16:19:57] scan: title angle(s) 1
[16:19:58] scan: 10 previews, 720x480, 29.970 fps, autocrop = 0/0/0/0, aspect 4:3, PAR 8:9
[16:19:58] scan: title (0) job->width:640, job->height:480
[16:19:58] libhb: scan thread found 1 valid title(s)
+ title 1:
  + vts 1, ttn 1, cells 0->0 (16 blocks)
  + duration: 00:00:00
  + size: 720x480, pixel aspect: 8/9, display aspect: 1.33, 29.970 fps
  + autocrop: 0/0/0/0
  + chapters:
    + 1: cells 0->0, 16 blocks, duration 00:00:00
  + audio tracks:
  + subtitle tracks:
[16:19:58] 1 job(s) to process
[16:19:58] starting job
[16:19:58] Height out of bounds, scaling down to 480
[16:19:58] New dimensions 640 * 480
[16:19:58] sync: expecting 2 video frames
[16:19:58] job configuration:
[16:19:58]  * source
[16:19:58]    + /dev/sr0
[16:19:58]    + title 1, chapter(s) 1 to 1
[16:19:58]  * destination
[16:19:58]    + Brave.mp4
[16:19:58]    + container: MPEG-4 (.mp4 and .m4v)
[16:19:58]  * video track
[16:19:58]    + decoder: mpeg2
[16:19:58]      + bitrate 9800 kbps
[16:19:58]    + frame rate: same as source (around 29.970 fps)
[16:19:58]    + dimensions: 720 * 480 -> 640 * 480, crop 0/0/0/0, mod 0
[16:19:58]    + encoder: MPEG-4 (FFmpeg)
[16:19:58]      + bitrate: 1000 kbps, pass: 0
[16:19:58] dvd: Region mask 0xf7
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.1.3
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdnav: DVD Title: BRAVE
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 412E6DD2
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): BRAVE
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/alberto/.dvdnav/BRAVE.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00f60000. Regions: 1 4

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x000001ff
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x000005cf
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x000005ed
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x0000063c
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_0.VOB at 0x0000087e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x00035cdb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_0.VOB at 0x00309c86
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB at 0x0030a0be
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_1.VOB at 0x0030d482
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_0.VOB at 0x0030fc31
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_1.VOB at 0x0031a1e8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_1.VOB at 0x00325600
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_13_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_16_1.VOB at 0x00326b3d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_17_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_18_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_19_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_20_1.VOB at 0x0035df16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_0.VOB at 0x0038bb9e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_21_1.VOB at 0x0038bc21
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_0.VOB at 0x003eeea5
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_22_1.VOB at 0x003eef15
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_23_1.VOB at 0x003eef2e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 23 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00f60000. Regions: 1 4
libdvdnav: decoder.c: [WARNING, unknown bits: 1000000000080000]
libdvdnav: decoder.c: [WARNING, unknown bits: 1000000000000000]
[16:19:58] reader: first SCR 146 id 0xe0 DTS 22254
[16:19:58] reader: done. 1 scr changes
[16:19:58] encavcodecInit: MPEG-4 ASP encoder
[16:19:58] mpeg2: "" (1) at frame 0 time 3003
[16:19:58] sync: first pts is 3003
[16:19:58] work: average encoding speed for job is 0.000000 fps
[16:19:58] mux: track 0, 12 frames, 5065 bytes, 101.20 kbps, fifo 16
Muxing: this may take awhile...[16:19:58] sync: got 12 frames, 2 expected
[16:19:58] mpeg2 done: 12 frames
[16:19:58] render: lost time: 0 (0 frames)
[16:19:58] render: gained time: 0 (0 frames) (0 not accounted for)
[16:19:58] libhb: work result = 0

Encode done!

HandBrake has exited.
```

Comment: Are the discs you are trying to back up Blu-Ray Discs?

Answer (score 26):

Here are the simple steps I do for stuff like this (And other multimedia issues):

1. Update system and Install **Ubuntu Restricted Extras**

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons
   ```
2. Install the Library needed to read all types of DVD and execute the script for it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libdvdread4   
   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
   ```

   This process includes preparing your DVD unit to be able to Read DVDs and download files needed from the Medibuntu site.
3. Add one of the PPA for Handbrake below:

   **STABLE PPA**

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
   ```

   **SNAPSHOT PPA**

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
   ```
4. Update repositories and install/upgrade handbrake

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli
   ```
5. If you get the following error then follow the instructions here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/install-handbrake-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/

   ```
   Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
   ```
6. If you already had it install then do

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Now we can proceed with the process of doing the backup

1. Open Handbrake

   [image]
2. Click on Source

   [image]
3. In the bottom left corner you can see an option that says **Detected DVD Devices** select your DVD from there since it might not work if you select it from the left panel.

   [image]
4. Wait a moment (Might take about 2 to 5 minutes if you are doing it like me through an external USB unit). Then simply select the **Start** button or change any Video/Audio settings and then click on the **Start** button.

   [image]

If you want to do it the terminal way then:

```
sudo HandBrakeCLI -i /dev/sr0 -o Ocean11.mkv
```

Assuming that the DVD unit is in `/dev/sr0`

NOTE - Posted this after testing on a computer that did not have nothing installed yet. It worked. Hope it works for you also.

Comment: Just a heads up Luis I think you might be missing the gtk or cli from the end of this line sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install handbrake. I used for example handbrake-gtk Thanks for your very well explained answer.

Comment: @CoalaWeb Sorry for the LONGGG delay, but just updated the answer. In the future, feel free to edit any answer you see with a mistake like that. Thanks friend.

Comment: +1 great answer for a recent convert from Windows to Linux!

Comment: This worked great - only thing I had to do differently to get it to work was change from `dvdnav` to `libdvdread` under File->Preferences->Advanced (at least for my DVD set of interest).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have libdvdcss installed? If not then open a terminal and copy and paste this command:
`sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update`

Then, after entering the command above, enter `sudo apt-get install libdvdcss`.

I believe this might help.

Comment: Discs are regular DVDs